# Heroku Server Keeps Crashing

Tags: django, heroku

I deployed a Django website on Heroku and sometimes I get lots of H10 (App crashed) messages in the log. Sometimes it ends up in some sort of a crash loop and I have to go in and restart the dyno manually. I'm running hobby dyno and that doesn't allow me to scale up or add redundancy options, but I want to find out what is causing the app to crash. The app deploys fine and starts as it should, the problem occurs in runtime when its serving client requests.

In the Heroku log I only see very basic info, very similar to this example from Heroku support:

"heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=myapp.herokuapp.com fwd=17.17.17.17 dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes="

It would useful to understand where the app crashed so that I can find and solve the root cause. (or could the problem be lack of resources at Heroku?)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you configured Django to log to `stdout` or `stderr` [as Heroku expects](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#writing-to-your-log)?